# Updating variable in a While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm having some problem with a household budget application.After I insert a new income or bill, checking the budget, the program add even the previous bill (or income) as commented in the Client code.

```
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Budget bud = new Budget();
    Bills[] expenses = new Bills[10];
    Income[] salary = new Income[4];
    boolean toContinue = true;
    String input = "";
    int menuItem = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int salCount = 0;
    float budget = 0;
    while (toContinue) {
        input = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("(1) Add an expense\n(2) Add the salary\n(3) Display Current Budget\n(4) Exit");
        menuItem = Integer.parseInt(input);

        switch (menuItem) {
        case 1:       //Add expense
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the expense");
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount for " + name));
            expenses[counter++] = new Bills(name, amount);
            break;
        case 2:     //Add salary
            String checkSal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter salary details");
            double checkAm = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of " + checkSal));
            salary[salCount++] = new Income(checkSal, checkAm);

            break;
        case 3:   // display current budget
            try {
                String expDisplay = "Expenditure\t             Amount\n";
                String salDisplay = "Salary\t                        Amount\n";
                float expenseSum = 0;
                float salarySum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < salary.length; i++) {
                    if (salary[i] != null)
                        salarySum += salary[i].Total();
                }

                for (int e = 0; e < expenses.length; e++) {
                    if (expenses[e] != null)

                        expenseSum += expenses[e].Total();
                }

                for (Bills e : expenses) {
                    if (e != null)
                        expDisplay += e.toString() + "\n";
                }

                for (Income p : salary) {
                    if (p != null)
                        salDisplay += p.toString() + "\n";

                }

                File fileBudget = new File("C:budget.txt");

                if (!fileBudget.exists()) {   //creating new txt
                    bud.setBudget(budget);
                    fileBudget.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("TEXT File Created");
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileBudget, false);
                    fw.write(bud.getBud() + "");
                    fw.flush();
                    fw.close();
                    budget = salarySum - expenseSum;  //calculating budget
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, expDisplay + "\n\n" + salDisplay + "\n\n" + "You spent: "
                            + expenseSum + "\n" + "Budget: " + budget);
                } else {

                    BufferedReader re = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:budget.txt")); //reading budget on txt file
                    while (true) {
                        String line = re.readLine();
                        if (line == null) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            float d = Float.valueOf(line);
                            bud.setBudget(d); //store the read value
                        }
                    }
                    re.close();    //end reading

                    float c = bud.getBud();   //taking budget value


                    // problem...there are even previous sum values!!
                    budget = salarySum - expenseSum + c;  // error 

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileBudget, false);
                    fw.write(budget + "\n");
                    fw.flush();
                    fw.close();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, expDisplay + "\n\n" + salDisplay + "\n\n" + "You spent: "
                            + expenseSum + "\n" + "Budget: " + budget);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            break;
        case 4:    //close program
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You closed the Budget Program!");

            System.exit(0); }}}}

//budget object
public class Budget implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public float bud;

Budget() 
{

}
public float getBud() {
    return bud;
}

public  void setBudget(float bud) {
    this.bud = bud;     }}

//Bill class
public class Bills {

private double amount;
private String name;

public Bills(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Bills(String name, double amount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Bills() {
    this("New Expense", 0); }

public String toString() {
    return name + "\t     " + "\t     " + amount;   }

public double Total() {
    return amount;  }}

//Income class
public class Income {

private double amount;
private String Salary;

public Income(String Salary, double amount) {
    this.Salary = Salary;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String toString() {
    return Salary + "\t     " + "\t             " + amount;
}

public double Total() {
    return amount;  }}
```

Comment: Do not initialise integer fields to `0` - this is done automatically.

Comment: Actually I get error if I don't do that @bcsb1001

Comment: then you are not compiling it java... neverthless it does not change anything so it's not related.
Another question which is not a real problem just asking for debuggin. Run debugger and deal with it, no one will do your job for you.

Comment: @Dominik I'm trying to understand how I could avoid adding the same value for every cycle . If it is not an appropriate question I will delete it.

Comment: Simply you have to debug your code. You can use debugger incorporated into your IDE or write some `System.out.println` calls to check state of different variables during runtime.

Comment: I tried with System.out.println but I still didn't understand how I can fix it. I asked just because I'm close to a deadline. Thank you for the suggest @Dominik

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong so that we can help?

Comment: After I insert an expense, for every time I choose to check the budget, the program add that expense (or income) to the budget instead of just checking. I'm trying to understand how to avoid it. @Rafael

Comment: I am sorry, your code has allot of logic errors, bad structure and the variable naming does not help an external programmer to understand your code (does not include comments as well). But what I saw is that you create a file and set (the first time) an un-calculated amount (i.e 0), then the problem should be in the else of you 3rd case branch.

Comment: @Rafael Thanks. I'm a newbie so I have to improve a lot. The problem should be there because every time Sum and sum last with the previous values.

Comment: Don't worry. I will suggest, edit your code, rename the variables by adding some sensible names like instead of Sum and sum use expensesSum and salarySum so others can understand. Also add some comments to describe your thoughts, then post the code here. Also add all the classes needed for someone to compile (i.e your Budget class)

Comment: still, for newbie, is it really worth to down-vote him so much? That's not great for motivation and engagement on this site, imho

Comment: @Rafael, thank you for the suggestions. I tried to made it more readable inserting even some comments.

Comment: @A.DiMatteo thanks for the support, even if I understand that some question like this could sound useless.

Comment: What is the purpose of the text file?

Comment: @Rafael I use it for storing the budget value, so I can read it after I close the program.

Comment: Have you consider that the storage of the budget value happens only once? When the file does not exist?

Comment: @Rafael  I checked, and the value is stored in both case (when the file doesn't exist and when it exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First of all here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < salary.length; i++)
{
   if (salary[i] != null)
   {
      salarySum += salary[i].Total();
   }
}

for (int e = 0; e < expenses.length; e++)
{
   if (expenses[e] != null)
   {
      expenseSum += expenses[e].Total();
   }
}
```

Each time your user enter [3] to see the details, these numbers added, and then the budget is calculated, this budget then is added to the file.

On the same session now, the user click again [3] and the above is repeated.

You should find a way to actually identify when the user have enter a new expense or a new salary, to avoid repeating the calculation of the budget and then the assignment to the file. (Boolean variable probably?)

Moreover here:

```
if (!fileBudget.exists()) {   //creating new txt
    bud.setBudget(budget);
    fileBudget.createNewFile();
    System.out.println("TEXT File Created");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileBudget, false);
    fw.write(bud.getBud() + "");
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
    budget = salarySum - expenseSum;  //calculating budget
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, expDisplay + "\n\n" + salDisplay + "\n\n" + "You spent: "
            + expenseSum + "\n" + "Budget: " + budget);
}
```

You always assign a zero value to the file. Even if the file is going to be created, maybe the user have already provided some budget, and you will lose this number. I think you have to calculate the budget there as well.

Edit:

A possible solution, and to simplify things, is to actually add to the file whenever the user enter a new salary, and subtract from the file whenever user enter an expense, so these two actions will take place in the first two cases (1 and 2) of the select statement. (Both actions, require that you read the text value first and then you add the new salary or you then subtract the new expense). This way your file will contain the latest calculated budget, and in the 3rd case you will only read the value from the file, which will contain the latest calculated budget, rather than calculating the budget in the 3rd case every time!

Comment: I will try to calculate budget in first and second case (writing the file in both cases) and just reading in the third one. I insert false in order to overwrite the file (that is what I saw online) and until now I never lose those numbers.

Comment: that is what I wrote up here...I had the same idea...the only problem is that my code is really bad written so it is a mess to put it in order....by the way thank you for your effort and support. Tonight I will keep working on it @rafael

Comment: Does this fixed the problem?

Comment: I still don't know but it sounds like a solution. I will write tonight the code again.I mean your edit was what I wrote in the comment, so I think that this could be a definitive solution.